# Creating data service in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a base data service then use it later

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular.module('app.core').factory('dataService', ['$http','$q', dataService]);

var dataService = function ($http, $q) {        
    var service = {
        httpPost: httpPost,
        httpGet: httpGet,
        httpDelete: httpDelete
    };
    return service;
........
```

Then trying to consume it by another service

```
(function () {
"use strict";
angular.module('app.features').factory('customerService',  ['dataService',customerService]);
var customerService = function (dataService) {
    var service = {
        search: search,
        ....
    };
    return service;
.....
```

But when I try to consume the customer service from the customer controller

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular.module("app.features").controller("CustomerCtrl", 
["$scope", "$rootScope", "$stateParams", "customerService", "$modal", "toaster", 
function ($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams, customerService, $modal, toaster) {
......
```

I then get the following error

*[ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got undefined*
and the error message is *Module 'ngLocale' is not available*

and when I remove the customer service reference from the controller the error is gone.
Also here is the modules declaration

```
//The root for all other modules
(function () {
'use strict';
angular.module("app", [     
"app.core", //angular and external code
    "app.directives",//Componenets
    //Custome modules, refacactor later to module per feature
    "app.features"
]);
})();

(function () {
'use strict';
 angular.module('app.core', [
    //Angular modules
    "ngAnimate",
    "ngCookies",
    "ngResource",
    "ngSanitize",
    "ngTouch",
    //3rd party
    "ngStorage",
    'ui.utils',
    'ui.load',
    "ui.router",
    "ui.bootstrap",
    "ui.jq",
    "ui.validate",
    "oc.lazyLoad",
    "pascalprecht.translate"
]);
})();
```

Scripts refernces

```
<!-- Vendor scripts -->
<script src="scripts/dependencies/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/dependencies/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/dependencies/angular/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/dependencies/angular/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/dependencies/angular/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/dependencies/angular/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/dependencies/angular/ngstorage/ngStorage.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/dependencies/angular/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/dependencies/angular/angular-ui-utils/ui-utils.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/dependencies/angular/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/dependencies/angular/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/dependencies/angular/oclazyload/ocLazyLoad.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/dependencies/modules/angularjs-toaster/toaster.js"></script>

<!--Application starter& Configuration-->
<script src="scripts/app/app.module.js"></script>

<!--Rename to app.js-->
<script src="scripts/app/main.js"></script>


<!--core-->
<script src="scripts/app/core/core.module.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app/features.module.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app/directives/directives.module.js"></script>

<script src="scripts/app/core/dataService.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app/config.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app/config.lazyload.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app/config.router.js"></script>

<!-- all my modules script goes here..-->

<!--Directives-->
<script src="scripts/app/core/ui-load.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app/directives/setnganimate.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app/directives/ui-butterbar.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app/directives/ui-focus.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app/directives/ui-fullscreen.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app/directives/ui-jq.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app/directives/ui-module.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app/directives/ui-nav.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app/directives/ui-scroll.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app/directives/ui-shift.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app/directives/ui-validate.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app/directives/ui-panel.js"></script>
```

Any ideas!

Comment: The code you provided does not contains "fn". Your issue comes from elsewhere.

Comment: Seems like you missed to refer `ng-locale.js`, please add relevant.. it doesn't seems to be clear..

Comment: is it an angular script? this is my first Angular 1 application? so I am not sure where to locate it

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check would be if you are defining the sub modules 'app.directives' and 'app.features'

```
angular.module('myApp.directives',[]);
angular.module('myApp.features',[]);
```

Above is the setter for these modules. I can see only the getter for the 'app.features' module where you are attaching the 'customerService' and 'CustomerCtrl' in your current code.

Also another thing to check would be the order of calling you js files in you index.html (if they are separate). If one is dependent upon another it should be called before the dependent resource.

Please give it a try and let me know. Sometimes these things bug a lot :) and believe me it has happened several times to me.

Comment: it is probably a dependency chain thing like you said, I`ve created a plnkr
[link](https://plnkr.co/edit/NAoEd4sOWNABy9xRvOIT?p=info) with the same logic and it works fine, but the error is really unclear

Comment: Yeah i think so too. This is how i made it work - [PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/weEAq6P035zW7p6CeFt2?p=preview)

Comment: Also, please mark as answer if you think it helped. Thanks!